# How to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1+\sqrt 2)^n+(1-\sqrt 2)^n}{(1+\sqrt 2)^n-(1-\sqrt 2)^n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1+\sqrt 2)^n+(1-\sqrt 2)^n}{(1+\sqrt 2)^n-(1-\sqrt 2)^n}.$$

I tried to expand using Newton's Binomial Theorem, but it didn't work.

Comment: Divide throughout by $(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ and observe that $\left|\dfrac{1-\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{2}}\right| < 1$.

Comment: @Muralidharan you might post your comment as an answer :)

Comment: observe that $|1-\sqrt{2}|<1$

Answer (score 5):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1+\sqrt 2)^n+(1-\sqrt 2)^n}{(1+\sqrt 2)^n-(1-\sqrt 2)^n}$
$= \lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1+a^n}{1-a^n} $ such that 
$a=\frac{(1-2^{\frac{1}{2}})}{(1+2^{\frac{1}{2}})}  $ , $|a|<1$. So
lim is equal to $\frac{1-0}{1+0}=1$

Comment: Dadrahm.Maybe you could add |a| <1.

Comment: Thank you .   .  .

Comment: Dahdram.A pleasure +.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, $|1-\sqrt 2| \lt 1$, so a high power of it will go to $0$.  $1+\sqrt 2 \gt 1$, so a high power of it will be large and positive.  We can ignore the two small terms and be left with the fixed ratio $1$.  Depending on what theorems you have proved about limits that may be enough.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

- $|1-\sqrt 2|<1 \implies (1-\sqrt 2)^n \to 0$

therefore

$$\frac{(1+\sqrt 2)^n+(1-\sqrt 2)^n}{(1+\sqrt 2)^n-(1-\sqrt 2)^n}\sim \frac{(1+\sqrt 2)^n}{(1+\sqrt 2)^n}=1$$

or more rigoursly

$$\frac{(1+\sqrt 2)^n+(1-\sqrt 2)^n}{(1+\sqrt 2)^n-(1-\sqrt 2)^n}=  \frac{(1+\sqrt 2)^n}{(1+\sqrt 2)^n}\frac{1+\frac{(1-\sqrt 2)^n}{(1+\sqrt 2)^n}}{1-\frac{(1-\sqrt 2)^n}{(1+\sqrt 2)^n}}\to \frac{1+0}{1-0}$$